Fan coil problem
I'm wondering if the fan speeds (hi/medium/low/auto) on the fan coil unit in my high rise condo automatically runs faster when the air conditioning is on as opposed to when the heating is on?
As I remember it, this is how the blower on the furnace worked when I lived in a house to push the cold air versus warm air, but I would like to know if it is similar with a fan coil unit

I suspect that this is part of the control system, so it will be different in every system based on how they are configured.  At minimum, you would need to give the models on the various parts, e.g. the thermostat, compressor, and furnace.  And the help that you receive might be to look up the answer in the configuration.
